# Acumatica - Add Action in Automation Schedule Screen when process is over

Tags: acumatica

I want to add an action when the process in the Automation Schedules screen ("SM205020") is over.

I try to override the button to append code lines but I can't override the button, the code of the button is hide (in a dll).

So, I put an event in the Last Executed Field but the event is never called (I put commitchange = true). I think is due to a Workflow but I don't see it, I think it's a hidden Workflow and I can't override it.

Have you an idea to put an action or an event when the process is over ?

Best,

Alexis

Comment: I recommend to add your code at the end of the specific action that you wish to capture.  In addition, automation schedules can record the history of each execution, if you choose that option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.